# What is the benefit to compile Lua as C++ other than avoid 'extern C' and get 'C++ exception'?

Tags: c++, lua

I'm quite new in Lua, and I want to embed Lua into our game project using C++. The first thing I notice, Lua is allowed to be compiled as C++ code, and from the doc, I've learned that this will eliminate the 'extern C' wrapping around Lua's headers, and also the error handling will be C++ exception instead of longjump/setjump.

My question is, besides these two differences, is there any other real benefit to compile Lua code as C++ code? These two don't real convince me, as, 1) it doesn't bother me to wrap c headers with 'extern C', 2) our project doesn't allow exception, so I have to change in luaconf.h to use longjump/setjump any way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those *are* the benefits of compiling Lua as C++. The `extern "C"` thing isn't even really the point; it's all about exception handling. And while your application forbids exceptions, not every C++ application does.

If you're using *all* of C++, you either have to take steps to prevent exceptions from passing through Lua (not the easiest thing in the world unless you're using a wrapper like Luabind) or to compile Lua as C++.

There are no other benefits of compiling Lua as C++. Exception handling *is* the reason why Lua can be compiled as C++.

Comment: Further to this: "Doesn't allow exceptions" could be interpreted two ways. 1. No user code can throw exceptions or 2. You compile with exceptions disabled. The difference is that many standard things will throw exceptions (like new) in case 1. In those cases you can expect "odd" behavior if one of those exceptions hits a lua C-C++ boundary.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: True, but if no user code throws exceptions, no user code *catches* them either. Which means `std::bad_alloc` will just bubble up past main and terminate the application. The stack doesn't even unwind in that case.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks for the explanation. As you said, we forbid the **use** of exception in user code, and we've got Google Breakpad to catch all unhandled exception and just let our game terminate. That's why exception handling in Lua doesn't make sense in our case.

Comment: @NicolBolas Agreed, However the termination looks different (and potentially confusing) if the code terminates at a C-C++ boundary, than bubbling up past main. I had this happen in a project I was working on, and it certainly made it harder to track down why the code was crashing. In addition in their case if Google Breakpad is catching other exceptions under normal circumstances, I suspect it will not catch them if thrown by something called by lua (but I dont know how breakpad works so I may be wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Another way of thinking about it might be to turn the question on its head and ask "Is there any benefit to compiling Lua in C (if we're already using C++)?"

If there's no advantage to compiling Lua as C—and as far as I know, there isn't—and you're already using C++ for your other code, compiling Lua as C++ too seems both simpler and potentially a little more robust, because you'll never have non-C++ stack frames to screw up stack rewinding if a callback into C++ from Lua happens to throw accidentally...