# Lua Catching Exceptions

Tags: c++, error-handling, lua

I am coding in Lua (and C++).
I want to catch exceptions and printing them into console. After `lua_atpanic` did not work correctly (program exited anyway). I thought to use exceptions.

Here is the edited part of my `luaconf.h`:

```
/* C++ exceptions */
#define LUAI_THROW(L,c) throw(c)
#define LUAI_TRY(L,c,a) try { a } catch(...) \
{ if ((c)->status == 0) (c)->status = -1; }
#define luai_jmpbuf int  /* dummy variable */
```

Here is the `init.lua` loaded:

```
int init = luaL_loadfile(L, "lua/init.lua");
if(init == 0)
{
    printf("[LUA] Included lua/init.lua\n");
    init = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
}
```

So now I thought, when using C++ exceptions I would edit that code to the following:

```
try {
    int init = luaL_loadfile(L, "lua/init.lua");

    if(init == 0)
    {
        printf("[LUA] Included lua/init.lua\n");
        init = lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
    }

    // Error Reporting
    if(init != 0) {
        printf("[LUA] Exception:\n");
        printf(lua_tostring(L, -1));
        printf("\n\n");
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    } else {
        lua_getglobal(L, "Init");
        lua_call(L, 0, 0);
    }
} catch(...)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hi", "Hio", NULL);
}
```

Just to see if anything happens. But nothing happens.
(The Lua error is calling a `nil` value)

Any ideas?

Comment: What precisely is output by the code? What does `lua/init.lua` contain? And what did you expect?

Comment: Maybe you read my text again. In the "Init" function, a nil value is called, that's the error (read last sentence). What lua/init.lua contains is unimportant. I want to catch errors and want to print them out in console (read second sentence, headline).

Comment: If an error happens in `Init`, according to your code, nothing will be output in the console, but the `MessageBox` should be called. Isn't it the case? BTW, it does not make sense to put `NULL` as the 4th argument for `MessageBox`, since that argument is a bit field.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the "MessageBox" is not called.

Comment: If you add a `printf` just before and after `lua_call(L, 0, 0);`, do you see their output on the console?

Comment: Did you actually recompile ***Lua*** (the library) when you made this change to luaconf.h?

Answer (score 4):

From [this](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_atpanic) you can see that `lua_atpanic` will always quit the application unless you do a long jump from within the panic function.

And from [this](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_pcall) you can see that calling `lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0)` will push an error message to the stack when you don't give it a stack location (errfunc is 0).

Since Lua is a C library, it does not use exceptions (C++ exceptions that is), so you will never `catch` such a beast from Lua code. Your code however can throw exceptions. To do this you'll have to compile the Lua library as C++.

Further reading:

[How to handle C++ exceptions when calling functions from Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615890/how-to-handle-c-exceptions-when-calling-functions-from-lua) and

[What is the benefit to compile Lua as C++ other than avoid 'extern C' and get 'C++ exception'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400016/what-is-the-benefit-to-compile-lua-as-c-other-than-avoid-extern-c-and-get-c)