# Compiling LuaJIT as C++?

Tags: g++, clang++, luajit

Can't seem to compile LuaJIT with g++ or clang++. Here are some DEBUG. Kindly let me know if I need to provide more information.

```
$ make CC="g++"
==== Building LuaJIT 2.0.4 ====
make -C src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nutanix/thirdparty/LuaJIT-2.0.4/src'
HOSTCC    host/minilua.o
host/minilua.c:370: error: uninitialized const ‘luaO_nilobject_’
host/minilua.c:604: error: redefinition of ‘const TValue luaO_nilobject_’
host/minilua.c:370: error: ‘const TValue luaO_nilobject_’ previously declared here
host/minilua.c:946: error: uninitialized const ‘luaP_opmodes’
host/minilua.c: In function ‘void luaG_typeerror(lua_State*, const TValue*, const char*)’:
host/minilua.c:2542: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘const char*’
host/minilua.c: At global scope:
host/minilua.c:2620: error: redefinition of ‘const lu_byte luaP_opmodes [38]’
host/minilua.c:946: error: ‘const lu_byte luaP_opmodes [38]’ previously declared here
make[1]: *** [host/minilua.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nutanix/thirdparty/LuaJIT-2.0.4/src'
make: *** [default] Error 2

$ make CC="clang++"
==== Building LuaJIT 2.0.4 ====
make -C src
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/nutanix/thirdparty/LuaJIT-2.0.4/src'
HOSTCC    host/minilua.o
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
host/minilua.c:370:21: error: default initialization of an object of const type
      'const TValue' (aka 'const lua_TValue') without a user-provided default
      constructor
static const TValue luaO_nilobject_;
                    ^
host/minilua.c:370:36: note: add an explicit initializer to initialize 'luaO_nilobject_'
static const TValue luaO_nilobject_;
                                   ^
                                    = {}
host/minilua.c:604:21: error: redefinition of 'luaO_nilobject_'
static const TValue luaO_nilobject_={{NULL},0};
                    ^
host/minilua.c:370:21: note: previous definition is here
static const TValue luaO_nilobject_;
                    ^
host/minilua.c:946:22: error: default initialization of an object of const type
      'const lu_byte [38]'
static const lu_byte luaP_opmodes[(cast(int,OP_VARARG)+1)];
                     ^
host/minilua.c:946:59: note: add an explicit initializer to initialize 'luaP_opmodes'
static const lu_byte luaP_opmodes[(cast(int,OP_VARARG)+1)];
                                                          ^
host/minilua.c:2491:13: error: assigning to 'const char *' from incompatible type 'long'
ar->namewhat=(ci)?NULL:NULL;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
host/minilua.c:2540:12: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'const char *' with
      an rvalue of type 'long'
const char*kind=(isinstack(L->ci,o))?
           ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
host/minilua.c:2620:22: error: redefinition of 'luaP_opmodes'
static const lu_byte luaP_opmodes[(cast(int,OP_VARARG)+1)]={
                     ^
host/minilua.c:946:22: note: previous definition is here
static const lu_byte luaP_opmodes[(cast(int,OP_VARARG)+1)];
                     ^
6 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [host/minilua.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nutanix/thirdparty/LuaJIT-2.0.4/src'
make: *** [default] Error 2

$ clang++ -v
clang version 3.6.1 (tags/RELEASE_361/final)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2
Selected GCC installation: /opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64

$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)

$ uname -a
Linux guo-dev 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 7 23:32:49 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So basically, I'm on a CentOS 6.5 system, with g++ 4.4.7 and clang++ 3.6.1. Trying to compile LuaJIT with a C++ compiler so that LuaJIT can safely throw C++ exceptions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: LuaJIT emits C code. C is not C++. C cannot be used/treated/compiled as C++. C code cannot be compiled using a C++ compiler, for the same reason why you can't run JavaScript in a Python interpreter. Use a C compiler for compiling C code, and your life will be easier.

Comment: @EtanReisner I mentioned the reason in the question -- so that LuaJIT can safely throw C++ exceptions.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I don't understand your comment that I can't use a C++ compiler. From the many pages I've read from googling, it's common practice to compile LuaJIT with a C++ compiler so that exceptions will be thrown instead of longjmp

Comment: Does [this section](http://luajit.org/extensions.html#exceptions) of the luajit page not indicate that this (mostly) just works already?

Comment: @EtanReisner apparently only if you compile LuaJIT with a C++ compiler. http://marcusirven.com/blog/2009/02/19/dangers-of-lua_error-when-using-c++.html

Comment: That's talking about lua not luajit. That page seems (to me a non-C++ user) to say that luajit handles those cases by default.

Comment: why would building with a C compiler generate code that throws exceptions? Relevant, though it's talking about Lua instead of LuaJIT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400016/what-is-the-benefit-to-compile-lua-as-c-other-than-avoid-extern-c-and-get-c

Answer (score 0):

Compiling LuaJIT with a C++ compiler would not solve the problem of "safely throw C++ exceptions" because parts of LuaJIT are written in assembly language and because at runtime machine code will be genenerated and executed dynamically if LuaJIT's Just-In-Time-Compiler is active. Therefore it is crucial that the machine code is able to handle C++ exceptions.

See also the section ***C++ Exception Interoperability*** at the LuaJIT's website http://luajit.org/extensions.html#exceptions. There is a table that explains under which conditions it is safe to throw C++ exceptions.

However the questions mentions the file `LuaJIT-2.0.4/src/host/minilua.c`. As is written the comment header of this file:

```
/* This is a heavily customized and minimized copy of Lua 5.1.5. */
/* It's only used to build LuaJIT. It does NOT have all standard functions! */
```

So in theory it should be possible to compile this stripped down plain C lua with a C++ compiler. But this would not affect the LuaJIT runtime.

If you want to compile plaina Lua (and not LuaJIT) with a C++ compiler, I would recommend to take the original Lua's source code from http://www.lua.org/ftp/, because the `minilua.c` in LuaJIT source is stripped down in such a way that it is not possible to compile it with a C++ compiler without modifications, whereas the original Lua source code can be compiled with a C++ compiler without bigger problems.